# Cannot read property 'createPublicClientApplication' of null in react-native-msal

Tags: react-native, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I am trying to configure the Azure AD B2C application for react native and using this [lib](https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal) for react-native. when trying to call init()
it gives error Cannot read property 'createPublicClientApplication' of null.
[image: error screenshot]

below is the MSAL config

```
auth: {
    clientId: 'fc8ecae3-0883-45f4-ac1c-013dfa11cb9c',
    authorityBase: 'https://stashcafe.b2clogin.com/tfp/stashcafe.onmicrosoft.com',
    policies: {
      signInSignUp: 'B2C_1_SignInUp',
      passwordReset: 'B2C_1_PasswordReset',
    },
    // redirectUri: Platform.select({ default: undefined }),
  },
  // web only:
  cache: { cacheLocation: 'localStorage' },

export const b2cScopes = ['https://stashcafe.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation'];
```

I have tried to add my own azure AD config but still same error.

Comment: This usually happens when you miss a step while installation. Maybe try following the installation docs again? https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal#install

Comment: There is also additional setup required: https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/blob/master/docs/android_setup.md

Comment: I had the same issue, see my answer here on what I did to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77389132/2150879. Ultimately, I think we need to wait for more version updates to be cross-compatable and backwards compatable.

Answer (score 0):

run

```bash
npm cache clean --force
```

and

```bash
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

This lib is dead. There are a few forks, but they are only working for specific expo versions and use cases.

Microsoft is using OpenID and other open standards, and now you can you use any library you want.

As i'm using Expo. I'm using [Expo AuthSession library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/new-name).

And it supports Azure Out of the Box: [Expo AuthSession for Azure](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#azure)

**Extra**: [Microsoft is renaming Azure AD to Azure Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/new-name)