# expo react-native-msal [TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPublicClientApplication' of null]

Tags: react-native, expo, msal

I'm having a similar issue as the question here: [Cannot read property 'createPublicClientApplication' of null in react-native-msal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162576/cannot-read-property-createpublicclientapplication-of-null-in-react-native-msa)

But I want to provide more insight as I have already tried the suggestions.

### Project used with

- nodejs
- expo/react-native
- android studio
- java jdk (using keytool)
- openssl: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/openssl-for-windows/openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip

### Guides

Expo Setup: https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/blob/master/docs/expo_setup.md

Follow step1 of android setup for expo: https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/blob/master/docs/android_setup.md

(optional) tried to follow the guide from this article, but it seems to have some missing pieces in it: https://medium.com/@tarunnarula/securing-react-native-msal-app-with-cross-validation-using-python-cecb8087881a

### Setup

Using android studio...
[image]

[image]

notice the package name and build successful in android studio
[image]

using the commandline...
[image]

gave the sha1 key output and the package name(com.ced.expomsaldemo) to our azure admin. He returned the following info...

```
{
  "client_id" : "<-- client uuid -->",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.example.expomsaldemo/<-- hash key -->",
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
        "type": "AzureADMyOrg",
        "tenant_id": "<-- tenant uuid -->"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### The Code

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import PublicClientApplication from 'react-native-msal';
import type { MSALConfiguration, MSALInteractiveParams, MSALResult } from 'react-native-msal';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { mainScreenSelections } from '@app/utils';
import { buttonStyles, globalStyles } from '@app/styles';

const config: MSALConfiguration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '<-- client uuid from azure -->',
    // This authority is used as the default in `acquireToken` and `acquireTokenSilent` if not provided to those methods.
    // Defaults to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<-- tenant uuid from azure -->/v2.0`
  }
};
const scopes = ['scope1', 'scope2'];

export default function Guest(): JSX.Element {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [isLoggingIn, setIsLoggingIn] = useState(false);

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoggingIn(true);
      const pca = new PublicClientApplication(config);
      const response = await pca.init();
      console.log('response:', response);

      // Acquiring a token for the first time, you must call pca.acquireToken
      const acquireTokenParams: MSALInteractiveParams = { scopes };
      console.log('acquireTokenParams:', acquireTokenParams);
      const acquireTokenResult: MSALResult | undefined = await pca.acquireToken(acquireTokenParams);
      console.log('acquireTokenResult:', acquireTokenResult);

      // On subsequent token acquisitions, you can call `pca.acquireTokenSilent`
      // Force the token to refresh with the `forceRefresh` option
      // const params: MSALSilentParams = {
      //   account: result!.account, // or get this by filtering the result from `pca.getAccounts` (see below)
      //   scopes,
      //   forceRefresh: true
      // };
      // const result: MSALResult | undefined = await pca.acquireTokenSilent(params);

      // // Get all accounts for which this application has refresh tokens
      // const accounts: MSALAccount[] = await pca.getAccounts();

      // // Retrieve the account matching the identifier
      // const account: MSALAccount | undefined = await pca.getAccount(result!.account.identifier);

      // // Remove all tokens from the cache for this application for the provided account
      // const success: boolean = await pca.removeAccount(result!.account);

      // // Same as `pca.removeAccount` with the exception that, if called on iOS with the `signoutFromBrowser` option set to true, it will additionally remove the account from the system browser
      // const params: MSALSignoutParams = {
      //   account: result!.account,
      //   signoutFromBrowser: true
      // };
      // const success: boolean = await pca.signOut(params);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log('error:', error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoggingIn(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ ...globalStyles.guestContainer, gap: 20 }}>
      <Text>Guest Screen</Text>
      <Pressable
        style={buttonStyles.btnMain}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(mainScreenSelections.dashboard.route as never)}
      >
        <Text style={buttonStyles.btnMainTxt}>Go To Dashboard</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable style={buttonStyles.btnMain} onPress={handleLogin}>
        <Text style={buttonStyles.btnMainTxt}>Login</Text>
      </Pressable>
      {isLoggingIn && <Text>Logging In...</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

### Steps to reproduce issue

[image]

press 'a' on your keyboard

Login
[image]

See error:
[image]

Comment: I've added a solution for your problem in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162576/cannot-read-property-createpublicclientapplication-of-null-in-react-native-msa/78195261#78195261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a solution, however this is what I did to fix it...

1. go to `<project_location>\node_modules\react-native-msal\android\build.gradle` and replace the following code snippet...

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('Msal_compileSdkVersion', 33)
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet('Msal_minSdkVersion', 16)
    targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('Msal_targetSdkVersion', 29)
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    disable 'GradleCompatible'
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  }
}
```

2. In the `<project_location>\app.json` add the following...

```
{
  "expo": {
    // ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "minSdkVersion": 23,
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

---

Again, I don't think switching version numbers in the node_modules is a maintainable solution, so imo I think they still need to work on making this backwards compatable, as there are other libraries I also have the same issue with where I have to use specific sdk versions that differ from version 33.