# expo prebuild (ios only) fails with react-native-msal "Error: [ios.appDelegate]: ...not in objective-c"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, azure-ad-msal

I had a similar issue with Android where I had to change the build version in the `node_modules` of `build.gradle` to match the SDK version used by the expo. See the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77389132/2150879

Now I'm seeing a different type of error with ios during expo's `prebuild` command complaining about not finding objective-c code, I don't even know where to begin where to start looking at why this is happening...

## The Command

`npx expo prebuild --platform ios`

## Azure's Error Output

```
Installing using npm
> npm install
- Config syncing
Using node to generate images. This is much slower than using native packages.
› Optionally you can stop the process and try again after successfully running `npm install -g sharp-cli`.

- Config syncing
✖ Config sync failed
Error: [ios.appDelegate]: withIosAppDelegateBaseMod: Cannot modify AppDelegate because it is not in objective-c
Error: [ios.appDelegate]: withIosAppDelegateBaseMod: Cannot modify AppDelegate because it is not in objective-c
    at /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-msal/plugin/build/withIosReactNativeMSAL.js:35:19
    at action (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-msal/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:235:29)
    at interceptingMod (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-msal/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:126:27)
    at action (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:206:14)
    at async interceptingMod (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:105:21)
    at async action (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/createBaseMod.js:61:21)
    at async interceptingMod (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:105:21)
    at async evalModsAsync (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/mod-compiler.js:202:25)
    at async Object.compileModsAsync (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/mod-compiler.js:124:10)
    at async configureProjectAsync (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/prebuild/configureProjectAsync.js:54:15)
```

## Error traced to node_modules\react-native-msal\plugin\build\withIosReactNativeMSAL.js

```
const withAppDelegateConfig = (config) => {
    return (0, config_plugins_1.withAppDelegate)(config, (mod) => {
        if (mod.modResults.language === 'objc') {
            mod.modResults.contents = setAppDelegate(mod.modResults.contents);
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('Cannot modify AppDelegate because it is not in objective-c'); // <---- error comes from here
        }
        return mod;
    });
};
```

## Expo Config app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my project",
    "slug": "my-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/qa-icon-1024.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "backgroundColor": "#001689",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/qa-splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#001689"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.mysite",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/qa-icon-1024.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#001689"
      },
      "package": "com.example.mysite",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "my_uuid"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "minSdkVersion": 23,
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "react-native-msal",
        {
          "androidPackageSignatureHash": "my_key"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

## Package.json to show package versions

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --port 8082",
    "android": "expo run:android --port 8082",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.8.3",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "^2.6.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-msal": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "yup": "^1.2.0",
    "zustand": "^4.4.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-jest-hoist": "^29.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-header": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.4.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw in a hack to `console.log(mod.modResults.language)` to see what the value actually was as to why this condition was false. It looks like the value was `objcpp`. It seemed so close to the `objc` value that all I did was change the line.

node_modules/react-native-msal/plugin/build/withIosReactNativeMSAL.js

change

```
if (mod.modResults.language === 'objc') {
```

to

```
if (mod.modResults.language === 'objcpp') {
```

Now it works. I can see the last code push for this line was 2 years ago, so maybe it wasn't updated and a bug needs to be filed. This is a duck-tape solution, but at least it works.